# How to remove “no file selected” text beside browse button while uploading file

Tags: asp.net

I want to remove “no file selected” text and file name beside browse button while uploading file.

Comment: You tried something? Little search on Google about custom file upload?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<button onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('inputfile').click();">Upload Photo</button>
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="inputfile"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fCWL2/

you can hide you input file and show the button which trigger the input file to click

then you can design you button for a better interface

i hope it will help